# NVIDIA Shield for android development?

Tags: android, debugging, nvidia, android-debug

Sorry if this sounds subjective, but I'm wondering if the NVIDIA Shield is any good for Android development. According to NVIDIA, the NVIDIA Shield is completely operated with Android and has compatibility with Android apps.

But I'm trying right now to get a good device for Android development and I'm not sure if this gaming device really is any good for it. I also don't know how easy it would be to debug and use apps on such a device.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is good. But it do not have a camera.  So It can be a problem to you.
The good point it use a stock android 4.2.1. And it is easy to root.